# boost.python code on module import

Tags: python, boost-python

I need to call InitGoogleLogging() when my C++ library is imported in Python.  My C++ library uses Boost.Python.

How do I call functions when the library is imported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no real "definitions" in python.  Any code you put in a **.py** module is **executed** when you **import** it.  It just happens to be that most of the time the code put in the package files is the "definiton" code like **class** or **def**.  In practice, that code still gets executed, it just creates your class and function definitions as a result.  Calling a function from the root namespace (indentation) in the module will cause it to get called as soon as the module is loaded.

Just put them into the __init__.py.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/techniques.html#python.extending_wrapped_objects_in_python where it talks about exporting your package with an alias and then flatning your namespace in **init**.py.

i.e. (this would be **__init__.py** in a a subdirectory named **foo**):

```
from _foo import *

InitGoogleLogging()
```

Another alternative is calling it directly from the C++ wrapper module:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    InitGoogleLogging();

    class_<Foo>("Foo")
        .def("bar", &bar)
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I like the second solution, but I need to get at argv.  Does boost::python give me a way to get at argv?  maybe I could call sys.argv[0]?

Comment: Do you mean argv for the application? If you do, then yes.

Comment: @aleksey: I do.  How do I get sys.argv[0] from within my C++ code?

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/python/doc/v2/exec.html.  One comment I have is why do you insist on doing all this from C++ side?  A lot of these things are a lot easier to do from Python.  If you're worried about showing your source code, you can always distribute just the .pyc or .pyo files without the .py file...

Comment: Yes.  It might make more sense to have a Python function that passes the necessary arguments to the C++ code, and use that in a module that imports your C++ code.  That feels cleaner, and is definitely more flexible.

Comment: @aleksey, Oh, I didn't understand that __init__.py was a module level thing.  The thing is that my module is just a .py file, so I would have to reorganize it so that it lived in a directory and then import DIRNAME.FILENAME?

Comment: @AFoglia: that's what I've done for now.  I guess you're right that it's pretty flexible, but the user has to remember to do this.

Comment: Depends what you define as your responsibility.  If you are responsible for the entire package, you would be the one writing the wrapper function.  You can even have the wrapper Python module call the function to pass sys.argv to the C-code on import (though that could cause more problems down the line).  Then there's nothing for the user to remember to do.

Comment: Is there any **Finalize** function in boost.python? I want to init MPI when importing the module and clean up when the module is unloaded.